# Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Document and others' TypeScript | XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I am stuck on a TypeScript error and I am a beginner in typescript someone can help me with this?

> Error on this code

```js
const setParams =(d_:any)=>{
        let p:String = ''
        for(let k in d_) p += k + '=' + d_[k] + '&'
        return p
}

const o = {data: {}} 
x.send(setParams(o.data))
```

Here is full Error on log

> const setParams: (d_: any) => String
> Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Document | XMLHttpRequestBodyInit | null | undefined'.
> Type 'String' is missing the following properties from type 'URLSearchParams': append, delete, get, getAll, and 7 more

Comment: Not sure what `x.send()` is but, I'm not getting any errors in TS for your setParams function, the error is somewhere else..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I solve the issue. the issue is on the setParams function I change (let p:String) to (let p:any)  and the problem is solved.